# Count all products in all subcategories recursively

Tags: python, django

I want to list all main categories (whose parent is `None`) and their direct children (level 1 only subcategories). I am using `django-mptt` to model my categories and so far I have only been able to count products from one direct child category.

My view is like this:

```
def show_categories(request):
    categories = Category.objects.filter(parent=None)
    return render(request, 'products/categories.html', {'categories': categories})
```

and my template:

```
<div class='categories'>
  <ul>
  {% for category in categories %}
    <li class='category'><a href="/shop/category/{{ category.slug }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
    {% for child in category.get_children %}
      <li class='subcategory'><a href="/shop/category/{{ child.slug }}">{{ child.name }} ({{ child.product_set.get_queryset.count }})</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

...so this works like this:

```
>>> from products.models import Product, Category
>>> c = Category(name='Books')
>>> c.save()
>>> c1 = Category(name='Textbooks', parent=c)
>>> c1.save()
>>> c2 = Category(name='Primary school', parent=c1)
>>> c2.save()
>>> p = Product(title='Math textbook', description='Math textbook for 4th grade', price=20, year=2018, category=c2)
>>> p.save()
>>> c.product_set.get_queryset().count()
0
```

...and I want it to return 1.

I need to count all products that are in 'child' category and its descendants, so there may be Books -> Textbooks -> Primary school, currently I'm only getting Textbooks, and I need to get Primary school too.

Is it possible to count all products in all subcategories recursively?

@EDIT:

My models, as per request:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('products:product-detail', kwargs={'id': self.id, 'slug': self.slug})

class Category(MPTTModel):
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('parent', 'slug',))
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_slug_list(self):
        ancestors = self.get_ancestors(include_self=True)
        slugs = [ancestor.slug for ancestor in ancestors]
        new_slugs = []
        for idx, ancestor in enumerate(slugs, 1):
            new_slugs.append('/'.join(slugs[:idx]))
        return new_slugs
```

Comment: Can you please share your models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added `get_recursive_product_count` method on my Category model:

```
def get_recursive_product_count(self):
    return Product.objects.filter(category__in=self.get_descendants(include_self=True)).count()
```

...and used that in a template like so:

```
<ul>
  {% for child in category.get_children %}
    <li class='subcategory'><a href="/shop/category/{{ child.slug }}">{{ child.name }} ({{ child.get_recursive_product_count }})</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: This makes one db query per category.  If you have 100 categories that's 100 queries. Have you figured out how to do it in one query?

Answer (score -1):

You're using django-mptt but not taking full advantage of it. The whole point of the MPTT algorithm is that you don't need to recurse, you can calculate things like the descendant count in a single go. And it gives you access to this in a single method: [`get_descendant_count`](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html#get-descendant-count).

Comment: This is getting number of subcategories in a category, and I need to get the number of *products* in all subcategories.